# Vulnerable IV and salt in AES encryption

Tags: c#, encryption, aes

I'm checking this AES encryption/decryption project http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/769741/Csharp-AES-bits-Encryption-Library-with-Salt

But I read that it has vulnerabilities with IV and salting. How can these vulnerabilities occur?

I know AES is immune to known plaintext attacks but if this implementation is wrong, is there a easy way to break it and get the key or plaintext?

Answer (score 3):

That code contains multiple versions. The last version with a random salt (*Getting Randomized Encryption Result with Salt*) is almost ok.

As you can see, the IV is generated from PBKDF2 which means that the **same IV will be produced when the same salt and password are used**. This is an undesirable effect, because it means that the same plaintext will create the same ciphertext. An attacker might deduce that you sent the same message again by only observing ciphertexts. This is of course not semantically secure which is why some randomness is necessary. **A way to solve that would be to use a random salt.**

Another problem with this code is the **low iteration count of 1000**. Nowadays, an iteration count of at least 60,000 up to a couple of million should be used. Otherwise, it gets easy for an attacker to try a lot of popular passwords and find the one password you used. So, increasing the iteration count would also severely limit the throughput for an offline attacker.

Another important problem with the code is that there is **no authentication of the ciphertext**. Depending on your system architecture, an attacker might launch a padding oracle attack and decrypt any ciphertext that you have sent with multiple online queries. The way to protect against that would be to use an authenticated mode of operation like GCM or EAX, or employ an [encrypt-then-MAC](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/202/13022) scheme with a strong MAC like HMAC-SHA256.

The last problem is that PBKDF2 is used to derive the key *and* the IV from the password. [This is not a good idea.](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/26540/13022)

**I've found [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10366194/1816580) which doesn't seem to have any of the problems discussed above.**

Comment: Well dissected. Another horrible piece of code on a code sharing website that gets almost 5 points by being horribly insecure. I should probably make a list or something. Make up your own salt; tsk.